# obtain a callbacks of sending mail

Tags: android, email

I am developing an application that needs to send inside an ordinary email.
The mail must be sent with the account set up on your smartphone. Through Intent.ACTION_SEND sending the mail goes smoothly.
Is there a way to know if the email was sent and if the sending has been successful?

Answer (score 0):

> The mail must be sent with the account set up on your smartphone

You assume the existence of such an account, and this is not a valid assumption. Bear in mind that just because they may have a *Google* account (e.g., for use with the Play Store), they may not be using Gmail, and there is nothing forcing users to use their Android device for any other email.

> Is there a way to know if the email was sent and if the sending has been successful?

No.

`ACTION_SEND` does not send email. `ACTION_SEND` lets the user share content of a specified MIME type. Whether the user chooses to send via email, who they send the email to, whether they change the content, whether they send the email at all, and so forth is up to the user, and your app is not informed of any of this.